# List of all UK sports clubs

Tags: data-request, data.gov, sports

- Hi Friends,

I'm looking for a list/ database containing a list of all UK sports clubs. Not just the community amateur sports clubs (CASCs) hosted by HMRC. Their status as professional or amateur, their geographic or sport distribution, or anything else is irrelevant. Just a list of identifiers would be great.

Any help? Much appreciated.

- Big data guy.